# Probability a random node is a leaf node

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How can I show that in the limit as $n$ approaches $\infty$, the probability of a given node of a tree containing $n$ vertices and $n - 1$ edges being a leaf node approaches $1/e$?

---

I think the problem I'm having with this is trying to get the right approach to take. I've been trying to write down a limit in terms of $n$ and using the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 - 1/n)^{n} = e^{-1},$ but I can't quite write down the probability.

I tried relating the probability for a tree on $n$ nodes to a tree on $n - 1$ nodes (recurrence relation), but I wasn't able to do so. I also tried coming up with a relation for the number of vertices with degree $1$ with the Handshaking Lemma, but this took me nowhere.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: How are you choosing a tree here? If your tree has $n-1$ vertices all connected to a central node, the probability will approach $1$; if your tree looks like a binary tree of fixed depth (up to some excess at the bottom layer), the probability will approach $1/2$.

Comment: The edges are selected randomly in the tree. All trees are equally likely

Comment: I am confused about how to "frame" this problem. How do we "create" the tree? Is it like this : we start with a vertex, add an edge and a new vertex from there, then choose one of these vertices uniformly at random, add an edge and a new vertex  from there, and so on? Then, once you've done this $n-1$ times, you pick one node at random from what tree you created, and ask if it is a leaf or not. Is this right?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: I take it to mean that if $\ell_n$ is the total number of leaves in all trees on $n$ nodes, and there are $t_n$ trees on $n$ nodes, then $\frac{\ell_n}{nt_n}\to e^{-1}$ as $n\to\infty$. E.g., for $n=5$ there are $3$ trees with a total of $9$ leaves amongst them, so the probability is $\frac35$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think that the question is about labeled trees so for $n=5$ the probability should be $\frac{4^3}{5^3}$. See my answer below.

Comment: @RobertZ: I saw. I’d rather that they were labelled, as it would make life much easier, but I see nothing in the statement that implies that the trees are labelled, so I chose to assume that they are not. It’s a point that the OP really needs to clarify.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the limit value $1/e$, I think that here we are talking about **labeled** trees (OP needs to clarify this point!).

By generalizing the classic [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula) $n^{n-2}$ which gives the number of trees on $n$ labeled vertices, we obtain the generating function
$$(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)^{n-2}=\sum \prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{d_T(v_k)-1}$$
where, on the right side, each monomial represents a tree $T$ with $n$ labeled vertices $v_k$ each with degree $d_T(v_k)$. Now, a given node, say $v_n$, is a leaf if and only if its  degree is $1$, that is $d_T(v_n)-1=0$. Hence the total number of trees with $n$ labeled vertices where $v_n$ is a leaf can be obtained by letting $x_n=0$, and the other $x_k=1$ in the above formula which yields $(n-1)^{n-2}$.

Hence the desired probability for trees with $n$ labeled nodes is
$$p_n=\frac{(n-1)^{n-2}}{n^{n-2}}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-2}\to \frac{1}{e}\quad \text{as $n\to\infty$.}$$

Example. For $n=4$ we have $4^2=16$ labeled trees and
$$p_4=\frac{\text{number of trees with a blue leaf}}{16}=\frac{9}{16}.$$

[image]